# ExtJs window sliding issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have got an extJs Windows rendered to Ext.getBody(). The page where it's rendered has a quick link option (custom fancy button) that when clicked shows another div. What i want to do is that if the quick links are not shown the extJs window should slide up and otherwise move down when the links are shown. I hope you guys can visualize what i am talking about. Please help me in this.
The problem that i am facing between is that the window is just stuck at its default position and has to be moved manually
Thanks..

Comment: please provide some code snippets of a jsFiddle to demonstrate this

Comment: the code is at my office and the next two days are off. I was hoping if someone could help me in this. I mean how can i slide extjs window up if there is some empty space above it ? Can it do this by itself ??

Answer (score 1):

Check out `Ext.util.Animate`: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Animate